# My desktop entry seem to have cached some old entries for some fields

Tags: .desktop, launcher

I am writing a desktop entry for an application that doesn't come with one (let's say `application A`). As usual, I just copy a desktop entry that exists already (let's say the desktop entry of `application B`), change the filename of the copy, and replace the fields' values (so that I don't have to look up the fields' names).

I initially kept `application B`'s icon, because that's generally the last thing I change (and I had no image yet). I also initially inverted the `Comment` and `GenericName` fields, by mistake. I tested my desktop entry with the launcher, saw that `application A` is correctly launched, but the generic name is wrong and the icon is the one from `application B`, so I changed the respective fields and... nothing? It's still the old field values? It's displaying the icon of the other application and also the wrong generic name.

I could have messed up the icon image absolute path, sure, but the new icon filename has nothing to do with `application B`'s icon, so it's very weird. Also, I deleted the field `Comment`, corrected the field `GenericName` and the current generic name displayed in the launcher is a string that is not written at all in the desktop file (the generic name displayed in the launcher is the old value I had entered initially for the `GenericName` field).

I obviously logged out, and when that failed to update the fields' values, I also rebooted my computer, and still the icon is the other application's, and the generic name is incorrect. The launcher still launches `application A` correctly, though.

Any idea how to correct all this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My desktop environment is a KDE environment, so I looked up the system cache and running the command `kbuildsycoca5  --noincremental` did the trick for me. Basically, it triggers a full rebuild of the KSycoca database. The source that explains it is here [[x]](https://userbase.kde.org/KDE_System_Administration/Caches).
I have now the correct icon and correct generic name.